# How to import an Image for VirtualBox

Tags: images, virtualbox, virtualization, import

I have VirtualBox installed on Ubuntu 64.
I have a few Images I need to import into my Virtual Box.
What I got is a file with *.ovf and a file with *.vmdk

What am I suppose to do with those files?

Comment: What, there's no 'Import Appliance' in File menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignore the .ovf files.

Open VirtualBox GUI.  Create a new VM.  Give it a name and pick an OS from the dropdown. Select a RAM amount.  Choose to use an existing hard disk.  Click the icon for the Virtual Media Manager, and add your VMDK file to the list.  Select it as the hard disk for your new VM.  Click Finish.  Select the VM and Start.

Note: the above written for VirtualBox 3.0.x.

Answer (score 4):

### With Oracle Virtual Box 4.0

The .ovf file can be used to import an appliance. You need both the ovf and the vmdk file.

1. Choose File >> Import Appliance
2. Navigate to the ovf file
3. Change settings (optional)
4. Click Done

The import begins.
Select your new VM and start it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you'd wanna use the command line util vBoxManage, use the command
`vboxmanage import ovf_file`.

This link shows you how to import from command line:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-import

This one http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf shows you the wizard for achieving the same

Answer (score 1):

As of 4.1.16  there is no NEW on the "Virtual Media Manger"  and while "Creating a new Virtual Machine" If you select a folder/name with an existing image (old) in it that you want to ATTACH it fails with "Can not create image there" message.